# pptp vpn connection and Internet at the same time (fedora12)

Tags: linux, networking, vpn, fedora, fedora12

I am using Fedora12. I have established a VPN connection, ie I can ssh to my 10.7.200.10
machine, but on the same time I cannot connect to the internet.

Does anybody know how to configure VPN + Internet at the same time in Linux.
Do I need to setup routes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

make sure you have the correct DNS settings when you use pptp.
usually the problem is name resolution once the channel is open.
This question belongs to superuser.com

Comment: I don't think that it is a matter of dns. I cannot connect using IP addresses as well. I think it is more related to routes.

Comment: if you're connecting through a firewall - make sure that the firewall allows vpn users to go out, check default gateway address.

Answer (score -1):

You should go to the Network - TCP IP V4/6 Properties and uncheck use remote gateway ; Windows is trying to use your VPN server as the Internet gateway.